# Restrict PhpMyAdmin to only one MySQL user

Tags: php, mysql

We have a MySQL Master and a Slave.

We use the slave to do some asynchronous and CPU intensive things like dump for Backup.

I want to avoid that people has some write access to our slave database.

What I want is:
- People can connect with any user on the master
- People can only connect with a specific user to slave (which has only select rights)

Is it possible?

Comment: You can set privileges for user for specific database?

Comment: Yes I can, but I want to restrict the root logging on the slave.

Comment: Then add read only privileges for users you want in slave.

Comment: I have the same users in slave and master. Both databases are identical.